# Security issue: bypassing reCaptcha in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, recaptcha, spam

I don't understand how they succeed to post so much spam even though I have recaptcha working (if verify_recaptcha...) Here's what I have in controller:

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if verify_recaptcha(:model => @post, :message => "Oh! There's a problem with reCAPTCHA's input!")
        if @comment.save
          #flash[:submit_notice] = 'Comment was successfully created.'
          Notifications.comment_notification(@comment).deliver
          format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to(@comment) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

And here's what I see in production.log:

```
Started POST "/en/comments" for 199.15.234.180 at 2012-11-01 19:50:48 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"&#x2713;", "authenticity_token"=>"yFrJyx7EPCG9d29+PEbkNOHlUpuyXIVSy5acGNOO0mU=", "comment"=>{"pos.....
```

Spam HTML follows. To my understanding, "as */*" is not HTML, which is a "normal" POST request. So I'm guessing the problem is somewhere there. Tried to google for */* didn't find anything. So what the heck is that?

**UPDATE: [SOLVED]**

It looks like not an issue, just someone who's bored persistently posts SPAM comments and solves reCaptchas (or maybe machine learning has advanced so far?). Probably Mollom is the next thing to add there :)

Comment: Where is `@post` defined? Do you not mean `:model => @comment` ?

Comment: The \@post was defined in the Posts controller (I'm rendering comment form there) and it's just \@post = Post.find( :first, ... ), as suggested in reCaptcha gem. But changing this to \@comment doesn't make any difference.